# check textbox if it has 4 integers

Tags: .net, vb.net, maskedtextbox

I have tried using `IsNumeric()` but it does not fulfill what I want to achieve.

I have a MaskedTextBox. 4-digits and - as PromptChar.

[image]

What I want is to trigger an event `checkSomething()` when there is 4-digit combination.

Say, 0001 then it will get an event. But nothing will happen when there is still a - in it. (000- | -001 and so on)

```
If mtPig.Text has 4digits then
.....
Else
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Private Function IsTextInteger(target As TextBox) As Boolean

    If Integer.TryParse(target.Text, Nothing) Then            
        If target.Text.Length = 4 Then Return True
    Else
        Return False
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: this returns true, but it only needs to have only one integer. It needs to have 4 integers to return true, else false

Comment: you need to have four digit or maximum 4 digit?

Comment: ya then it will work.It will check first whether it is integer or not if yes then it will check it has 4 digit

Comment: Maybe there's some bug on MaskedTextBox. I'll change the control

Answer (score 0):

Look at the MaskCompleted (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.maskcompleted.aspx) and MaskFull properties.

MaskCompleted - all mandatory characters have been entered

MaskFull - all mandatory and optional characters have been entered

You could use the Validating event as @Vignesh has, or KeyPress if you want to do it keystroke by keystroke.

Comment: better answer I would think, but I've already changed my controls to a normal textBox.